# How to use EasyFind (or a similar application) to search inside ~/Library?

Tags: applications, search

I would like to use [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) to search inside the folder `~/Library/Application\ Support/Anki2/`. Unfortunately, the `Library` subfolder is not listed under the home folder in the `Select A Folder...` dialog box. Is there a way around it? Alternatively, is there another file-searching GUI-based application that will enable me to search inside said folder?

Comment: It will search any folder you drag to it; or just search Invisible files & folders for the entire drive.

Comment: You can make that folder visible if you want: Paste this to Terminal.app `sudo chflags nohidden "/Library"
` It'll likely ask you to enter your admin password. Press enter after you've entered your pass. If you want to hide that folder again: `sudo chflags hidden "/Library"`. Note that even thought it is hidden, you can still open that folder in finder if you do `Go > Go to Folder...` and enter `/Library`.

Comment: ^ Note it's ~/Library not /Library. It probably doesn't need `sudo` either, as it's your own folder.

Comment: Nor does it need the quotes -  `chflags nohidden ~/Library` rather than `chflags nohidden "~/Library"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to just tell EasyFind to search the entire drive for invisibles.

It's not very efficient, but it's very easy.

Alternatively, it will search any folder you drag to the 'location' drop menu.

For a folder which is normally hidden, such as ~/Library, there are several methods to reveal it.

- Finder > Go Menu - hold  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  & the User Library will be revealed in the menu
   <sup>From comments, this may be yet another of those commands that changes by System Language. Adding Shift may apparently be necessary in some languages.</sup>
- Use the Go To Folder... command from the Go Menu or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>   & type `~/Library`
  You can always go to any invisible folder this way, however deeply it's nested, for instance `~/Library/Application Support/Anki2/`. Note it doesn't need the space escaping.
- Permanently unhide by going to Finder,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>  for new window;  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>H</kbd>  to go to Home folder;  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>  for View Options, then check the Show Library Folder box.
- Permanently unhide using Terminal & the command
  `chflags nohidden ~/Library`
  Revert with `hidden`
- Unhide all hidden files & folders using Terminal &
  `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE;killall Finder`
  Revert using `FALSE`

Comment: Thanks. Very exhaustive. I'd like to comment about your first bullet point. In my system it's not enough to hold down Opt ⌥; you need to hold down Shift ⇧ too.

Comment: Odd. Never heard of that. adding opt or shift can often make alternative menus appear, but for me using both does nothing. I'm on UK English, what are you on?